# How to fix: gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python"'

Tags: windows, yarnpkg, node-gyp, node-sass

I've removed node modules and reinstall it but not solving the problem. If I run `yarn add node-sass`, the following error comes up in my terminal

```
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack:
gyp verb `which` failed    'Error: not found: python\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

node and npm version are

```
node- v 10.16.0
npm -v 6.9.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Follow the step:

```
npm install -g node-gyp

npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Comment: the first command ran successfully but the second gave this error:   npm ERR! Failed at the windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall script. then i ran yarn add node-sass again but still get the same error i posted above.

Comment: Can you use it:  npm install --global --production windows-build-tools@4.0.0. Run on cmd administrator mode.

Comment: i used it and it also throw another error which i have provided below

Comment: I get this message when running 2nd command  `- npm WARN deprecated windows-build-tools@5.2.2: Node.js now includes build tools for Windows. You probably no longer need this tool`. See https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools for details.